# Await a variable from an event

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, input, async-await

i am trying to code an interactive interface, for that i listen to key inputs with readline & process.stdin inside a class.
My code right now is

```
Console.on('input', (input) => {
    console.log(input); // Return a key Input
    process.exit(0)
})
```

What i would like to be able to do is listen to the event exceptionally in an await.
So i can define variable on the spot by waiting for the next user input .
Example:

```
var input = await event(Console, 'input');
console.log(input);
/* 
   event on this case would be a custom functions suggested since i don't know how
   i could do that properly . . .
*/
```

Is there a way to do that somehow ? Please let me know if my question is not

Comment: if the event only happens once, then you can probably do what you want

Comment: I am trying to keep the code as compact as possible. Therefor i picked the Answer that was gave previously, it was exactly what i needed.

Comment: Please don't add the answer to your question. Add a new answer if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the previous answer here is my final code

```
WaitFor(eventName) 
{
    return new Promise((resolve) => 
    {
        this.on('disconnect', () => {
            resolve(null); // Got disconnected from WebSocket, so we cancell the user input
        });
        this.on(eventName, (value) => { 
            resolve(value); // Got the event called
        });
    });
}
```

Example of use:

```
var licenseKey = await Console.WaitFor('input');
console.log(await licenseKey);
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have an `off` to go with your `on` method, yes, `event` could look like this:

```
function event(source, eventName) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        const handler = (value) => {
            resolve(value);
            source.off(eventName, handler);
        };
        source.on(eventName, handler);
    });
}
```

That creates a promise and subscribes to the event. The next time the event occurs, the handler fulfills the promise with any value it receives (that part is optional) and unsubscribes from the event.